# Why is VS 2010 unable to find/load htmllite.dll when installing?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to install VS 2010 in my PC but when I clicked on setup file it shows an error like:

`unalble to find/load htmllite.dll`

But `htmllite.dll` already exists within the file.

The same thing is happening again when I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008

`unalble to find/load setup.rll`

But I already have `setup.rll` file.

Answer (score 1):

After you mount the image, do not run directly, but copy all the files into a folder on your computer , and after that run setup.exe. I had the same issue with microsoft visual studio 2010 on my laptop with windows 8. Good luck!